# Why does Drupal CCK store dates in the database using unix timestamps and not native mysql DATETIME?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-6

For example:

- Is it because the user can configure the timezone via Drupal's admin interface - versus MySQL's timezone, which is not handled via the Drupal interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While used predominantly in PHP/MySQL configurations, Drupal supports multiple database technologies, including PostgreSQL natively, and additional DBs, such as MSSQL, are supported by additional modules.

Timestamps not tied to a particular databases date/time functions helps the CMS obtain some database independence.

Comment: That means then that Drupal has chosen "database independence" over "epoch independence". I'd rather code in PHP for different databases (which is possible), than not being able to store dates before 1970. I think that's an even bigger limitation.